# Как реализовать корзину в Telegram боте на Python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, бот

Скажу сразу, в программировании - новичок, пишу где-то 2 месяца. Где-то месяц назад начал писать бота для Telegram на языке Python, пишу на библиотеке `telebot`. Практически все сделал, осталось доделать корзину, но не понимаю как осуществить затеянное. Снизу приложу примерную схему работы корзины (заранее извиняюсь за свой корявый почерк).

Если у кого-то есть подобный код который соответствует моему описанию, буду рад принять или кто не поленится написать, буду очень признателен (сроки поджимают). Снизу оставлю примерную логику работы корзины.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добрый день. Попробуйте библиотеку aiogram в интернете сможете найти точно информацию с примерами как сделать такое. Возможно без корзины но продажу товара точно можно. Касательно кода, то думаю целый код вам никто не сбросит, цель данного ресурса помощь с ошибками и обучении, а не в написании за вас кода.

Comment: Это работа с БД. Вам нужно создать таблицу, в который Вы будите хранить список товаров, выбранный человеком. Легче всего для этих целей подойдет SQLite.

Comment: @stalinReturned предложил прекрасную идею. Но в будущем рекомендую перейти на `posgresql`